# Is there a way to set up pytest to run a webapp2 server for coverage reports?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, code-coverage, pytest

I'm currently setting up automated tests for a webapp2 server and I'd like to get a coverage report. I'm using pytest and pytest-coverage which works for local code, but the issue is that I'm making requests to the server (running locally) and the code run by the server isn't included in the coverage report. Is there a way to set up pytest to run the server itself so that I can have handlers and so-on included in the coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

In case there's anyone in a similar situation, [pytest-xprocess](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xprocess) could be used here. You could write a simple fixture like the following to start an instance of your server and make it available in your tests:

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest
from xprocess import ProcessStarter

@pytest.fixture
def myserver(xprocess):
    class Starter(ProcessStarter):
        # startup pattern
        pattern = "PATTERN"

        # command to start process
        args = ['command', 'arg1', 'arg2']

    # ensure process is running and return its logfile
    logfile = xprocess.ensure("myserver", Starter)

    conn = # create a connection or url/port info to the server
    yield conn

    # clean up whole process tree afterwards
    xprocess.getinfo("myserver").terminate()
```